# Pass List of objects from angular to spring

Tags: angular, list, spring-boot, rest

I want to pass a List of objects from angular to spring with rest api but i could not match the array that i'm passing to the service in angular with the one that i'm passing to the controller in Spring and i'm getting this error :

```
ERROR Invalid JSON input: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.backend.guestnhouse.payload.request.RoomRequest` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.backend.guestnhouse.payload.request.RoomRequest` out of START_ARRAY token
     at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
```

I have this method where i'm passing a List of objects to @RequestBody :

```
@PostMapping
public String addRoom(@RequestBody RoomRequest roomRequest) {
    return roomService.addRooms(roomRequest);
}
```

This is the body that i want to pass to the method

```
    {
     "rooms":[
              {
              "startdate":"2020-04-25",
              "enddate":"2020-04-29",
              "roomName":"room 1",
              },
              {
              "startdate":"2020-04-25",
              "enddate":"2020-04-29",
              "roomName":"room 2",
              }
            ]
    }
```

This is my method in component.ts

```
addRoomstobebooked(rooms:any){
    this.roomsService.addRooms(rooms).subscribe(
        data=> {
            this.message=data
            console.log(this.message)
        })
  }
```

This is my service

```
addRooms(rooms::any ): Observable<any> {
return this.http.post(`${API_URL}`,rooms);
 }
```

This is the array that i have in angular that i'm passing to the service

```
[ 0: {
    "startdate":"2020-04-25",
    "enddate":"2020-04-29",
    "roomName":"room 1",
    },
1: {
    "startdate":"2020-04-25",
     "enddate":"2020-04-29",
     "roomName":"room 2",
    },
 ]
```

How to match the List that i have in Angular with the one that i want to pass to the method in Spring?

Thank you

Comment: by the looks of the error message, you are not passing an array to the API, so it cannot parse what it is getting. `0: {}, 1: {}` isn't a valid array.

Comment: Yes that's the cause of the error, i want to know how to pass a valid array to the api.

Comment: Where do you add the entries to the "array"? So where do you put a room into rooms?

Comment: Im confused at how you get that array format without the angular app complaining. Its not valid array or JSON unless there is more to that data structure that hasn't been shared.

Comment: It's a simple array in angular that's why the angular app is not complaining .              
  this is my function where add a room in the rooms array                                                                                                                     
 addRoom(room : Room) {                                                                                            
           
            this.rooms.push(room)
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Spring Controller method specifies that the body of the request should be parsed into an instance of the RoomRequest class.

Your Angular application is POSTing an Array.

So, the Spring error is due to the fact that Spring is trying to parse the JSon that it receives to an Object, but the JSon string that it receives starts with a left square bracket (a "["), which is the start of an array.

You can fix this by POSTing an instance of a Typescript class that matches the structure of your Java RoomRequest class. Presumably, the RoomRequest class (on both sides) will contain an array of objects that looks like the data that you are currently posting.

Comment: RoomRequest class is a DTO that contains a List of Rooms , Spring is expecting a List.

Comment: That's exactly the problem - RoomRequest is an Object that contains a list, it is not itself a list. So Spring expects a list, but gets an object containing a list instead.

Comment: I passed the array as string and used Gson() in Spring , but i'll try your way. Thank you